# Parsing XML tags into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xml, parsing, tags

I have XML file as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<pbsCrew>
    <schedulePeriod>
        <startDate>2022-06-02</startDate>
        <endDate>2022-07-01</endDate>
    </schedulePeriod>
    <crewMembers>
        <crewMember>
            <id>12345</id>
            <firstName>John</firstName>
            <middleName>S</middleName>
            <lastName>Doe</lastName>
            <seniorityNumber>2</seniorityNumber>
            <base>DFW</base>
            <division>I</division>
            <seat>CA</seat>
            <flightQualification>
                <hitcities/>
                <monthlyMax>9983</monthlyMax>
                <volMax>0</volMax>
                <restricted75HrCities>
                    <city>
                        <code>GUC</code>
                    </city>
                    <city>
                        <code>MSO</code>
                    </city>
                    </city>
                </restricted75HrCities>
                <equipmentTypes>
                    <equipment>
                        <type>777</type>
                    </equipment>
                </equipmentTypes>
                <green>false</green>
                <isVaccinated>true</isVaccinated>
            </flightQualification>
            <bidQualification>
                <canBid>true</canBid>
                <canBeAwarded>true</canBeAwarded>
            </bidQualification>
        </crewMember>
        <crewMember>
            <id>22222</id>
            <firstName>JANE</firstName>
            <middleName>R</middleName>
            <lastName>DOE</lastName>
            <seniorityNumber>8</seniorityNumber>
            <base>DFW</base>
            <division>I</division>
            <seat>CA</seat>
            <flightQualification>
                <hitcities>
                    <hitcity>
                        <code>OAX</code>
                    </hitcity>
                    <hitcity>
                        <code>MSO</code>
                    </hitcity>
                    <hitcity>
                        <code>US</code>
                    </hitcity>
                </hitcities>
                <monthlyMax>7642</monthlyMax>
                <volMax>0</volMax>
                <restricted75HrCities/>
                <equipmentTypes>
                    <equipment>
                        <type>787</type>
                    </equipment>
                </equipmentTypes>
                <green>false</green>
                <trainerLineCheck>false</trainerLineCheck>
                <trainerLineIndoctrination>false</trainerLineIndoctrination>
                <isVaccinated>true</isVaccinated>
            </flightQualification>
            <bidQualification>
                <canBid>true</canBid>
                <canBeAwarded>true</canBeAwarded>
            </bidQualification>
        </crewMember>
   </crewMembers>
</pbsCrew>
```

I would like to parse the **crewMember** tag and get the **id, firstName, lastName** from there and the **isVaccinated** tag from **flightQualification** all into one Pandas dataframe like below:

| ID | firstname | lastname | isVaccinated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | John | Doe | True |
| 22222 | Jane | Doe | True |

I know this will involve a for loop to retrieve the firstName and lastName values, but having trouble extracting all the values I need. Is there a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Although it can be done with elementtree or lxml library using the loop, same goal can be achieved using pandas read_xml() method using the stylesheet attribute. This attribute specifies an XSL stylesheet used to transform original xml. In your case it's needed to flatten it, making all elements of interest to be contained within one parent element serving as a row.

Here is the example:

```
xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<pbsCrew>
    <schedulePeriod>
        <startDate>2022-06-02</startDate>
        <endDate>2022-07-01</endDate>
    </schedulePeriod>
    <crewMembers>
        <crewMember>
            <id>12345</id>
            <firstName>John</firstName>
            <middleName>S</middleName>
            <lastName>Doe</lastName>
            <seniorityNumber>2</seniorityNumber>
            <base>DFW</base>
            <division>I</division>
            <seat>CA</seat>
            <flightQualification>
                <hitcities/>
                <monthlyMax>9983</monthlyMax>
                <volMax>0</volMax>
                <restricted75HrCities>
                    <city>
                        <code>GUC</code>
                    </city>
                    <city>
                        <code>MSO</code>
                    </city>
                </restricted75HrCities>
                <equipmentTypes>
                    <equipment>
                        <type>777</type>
                    </equipment>
                </equipmentTypes>
                <green>false</green>
                <isVaccinated>true</isVaccinated>
            </flightQualification>
            <bidQualification>
                <canBid>true</canBid>
                <canBeAwarded>true</canBeAwarded>
            </bidQualification>
        </crewMember>
        <crewMember>
            <id>22222</id>
            <firstName>JANE</firstName>
            <middleName>R</middleName>
            <lastName>DOE</lastName>
            <seniorityNumber>8</seniorityNumber>
            <base>DFW</base>
            <division>I</division>
            <seat>CA</seat>
            <flightQualification>
                <hitcities>
                    <hitcity>
                        <code>OAX</code>
                    </hitcity>
                    <hitcity>
                        <code>MSO</code>
                    </hitcity>
                    <hitcity>
                        <code>US</code>
                    </hitcity>
                </hitcities>
                <monthlyMax>7642</monthlyMax>
                <volMax>0</volMax>
                <restricted75HrCities/>
                <equipmentTypes>
                    <equipment>
                        <type>787</type>
                    </equipment>
                </equipmentTypes>
                <green>false</green>
                <trainerLineCheck>false</trainerLineCheck>
                <trainerLineIndoctrination>false</trainerLineIndoctrination>
                <isVaccinated>true</isVaccinated>
            </flightQualification>
            <bidQualification>
                <canBid>true</canBid>
                <canBeAwarded>true</canBeAwarded>
            </bidQualification>
        </crewMember>
   </crewMembers>
</pbsCrew>
'''

import pandas as pd

stylesheet = '''<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <members>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//crewMember"/>
        </members>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//crewMember">
        <crewMember>
            <ID>
                <xsl:value-of select="./id"/>
            </ID>
            <firstname>
                <xsl:value-of select="./firstName"/>
            </firstname>
            <lastname>
                <xsl:value-of select="./lastName"/>
            </lastname>
            <isVaccinated>
                <xsl:value-of select="./flightQualification/isVaccinated"/>
            </isVaccinated>
        </crewMember>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>'''

df = pd.read_xml(xml, xpath="//crewMember", stylesheet = stylesheet)
print(df)
```

Here stylesheet transforms original XML to the following form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<members>
   <crewMember>
      <ID>12345</ID>
      <firstname>John</firstname>
      <lastname>Doe</lastname>
      <isVaccinated>true</isVaccinated>
   </crewMember>
   <crewMember>
      <ID>22222</ID>
      <firstname>JANE</firstname>
      <lastname>DOE</lastname>
      <isVaccinated>true</isVaccinated>
   </crewMember>
</members>
```

This allows us to use xpath `//crewMember"` taking children of a `crewMember` element as dataframe row fields.